# How to Access Installed python directory/'site-packages' Folder for a VM Instance on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, directory, google-compute-engine, site-packages

I am currently using GCP through a VM instance to run python 3.6. I can see my notebooks and data I've added/created, however I can't see my root folder or package details and need to edit a core module under site-packages, which would normally be under Python3.6 folder. Is there a way to access this through SSH or terminal?

I have tried to basic Pushd to where I expected it to be, no luck:

[image]

Comment: I found mine in a CE instance by running $python3 -m site --user-site

Comment: Totally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @Albert Albesa in comments, typing `python3 -m site --user-site` will give you the adress and you can use `pushd` to navigate to it